# Tomcat Server Just Hangs - log4j Warn

Tags: java, tomcat

So no idea why but tomcat7 seems to be just hanging. When I enter in localhost or my own ip that it's running on, it just sits there loading. And when doing 'startup' cmd in the tomcat directory, I get some random JSSE java error but then a log4J warning saying please initialize the log4j system properly.

Not sure why a WARN would prevent it from starting. I still see that tomcat service is listening on 443 and java is listening on 80.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you trigger a thread dump and take a look - you will be able to see what each thread is doing and more importantly, what each thread is waiting for. You can always ask for help here if you have trouble interpreting the data.

Comment: What's the best way to do a thread dump?

Comment: Google "java thread dump": first (of many useful) result: https://blog.fastthread.io/2016/06/06/how-to-take-thread-dumps-7-options/